# При открытии pop up автоматически проигрывается видео youtube

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, youtube-api

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при открытии popup автоматически включалось видео с youtube. Прилагаю свой код:

```js
//Pop video.

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.video__item-videowrapper').on('click', function() {
    $('.video').toggle();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.video__top-icon').on('click', function() {
    $('.video').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
/* SCCS */

.video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  color: #acacac;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  display: none;
}

.video__mid-player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.video__mid-playercontainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 50vh;
}

#ytplayer {
  width: 900px;
  height: 506px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video">
  <div class="video__top">
    <div class="video__top-close">
      <div class="video__top-icon">
        <div class="video__icon-line"></div>
        <div class="video__icon-line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video__mid-playercontainer">
      <div class="video__mid-player">
        <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EePTirAs6Ig?autoplay=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Вот собственно код. Изначально у POP UP стоит display: none и при нажатии на ссылку он открывается. Но видео игнорирует display: none у pop up и играет фоном. Необходимо сделать чтобы оно автоматически включалось при нажатии на pop up. Прошу помощи у опытных людей, желательно с кодом :) Заранее спасибо. Очень хочется разобраться, как это делать правильно.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
    $('.video__item-videowrapper, .video__top-icon').on('click', togglePopup);
});

function togglePopup() {
  var iframe = $('#ytplayer');

  if( iframe.hasClass('is-playing') ) {
    iframe.removeAttr('src');
  }else{
    iframe.attr('src', iframe.data('src'));
  }

  iframe.toggleClass('is-playing');
  $('.video').toggle();

}
```

```html
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EePTirAs6Ig?autoplay=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Что-то вы свой код не дописали, в частности, где элементы управления, заявленные в js?

Comment: При просмотре старого js, присутствует выборка .video__item-videowrapper и .video__top-icon. Видимо не весь html сбросили.

Comment: .video__item-videowrapper используется для клика на основной страницы для раскрытия самого popup, а .video__top-icon служит иконкой крестика для его скрытия. К слову тот код который Вы предоставили выше не подошел и видео по-прежнему работает сразу после загрузки страницы.

Comment: Вы iframe поменяли на тот, что я сбросил?

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно будет передать параметр в iframe autoplay="1".

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EePTirAs6Ig?autoplay=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen autoplay="1"></iframe>
```

при закрытии менять параметр на autoplay="0"